# Capture return code of Perl system command with redirection

Tags: perl

I am trying to capture the return code of a `system` call. To make it simple, consider a command that you know returns code 1, for example the following bash script `t.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
exit 1
```

Then consider:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $res=system("t.sh");
say ($?>>8);

$res=system("t.sh &>/dev/null");
say ($?>>8);
```

which prints

```
1
0
```

Why does the second `system` call (the one with error redirection) give me a zero return code?

Comment: "&>" should be "2>". You are running the command in background, and gets the 0 exit code

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to redirect both standard output and standard error.. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html. According to that page, the syntax should be `&>` ?

Comment: Then use `$res = system("t.sh > /dev/null 2>1")`

Comment: Thanks @Miller, this works! (It would be nice to know why `&>` is not working though, since it is given in the manual)

Comment: @HåkonHægland `&>` is a relatively new Bash feature (introduced in v4.x). Check your version with `bash --version`; `&>` works properly on my system with v4.1.2. `&>` is semantically equivalent to `>word 2>&1`, so you could do `system('t.sh > /dev/null 2>&1');`. Note the `&` in `2>&1`; if you leave this off, you will create a file named `1` in the current directory.

Comment: Also note that `&>` [does not work](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) in many other shells, so you should use the more cross-platform version `> file 2>&1` anyway.

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot ! Very good comment. I actually wondered where the file `1` came from :) (You could post your comment as an answer)..

Comment: I misread the changelog. `&>>` was the new operator in 4.x. Even so, `&>` shouldn't be used, and *may* have had issues in previous versions. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't duplicate your issue with Bash v4.1.2:

```
$ perl -wE 'system( q{/bin/bash -c "true &> /dev/null"} ); say $? >> 8'
0
$ perl -wE 'system( q{/bin/bash -c "false &> /dev/null"} ); say $? >> 8'
1
```

However, the `&>` redirection operator is not portable and [should generally be avoided](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). I'm not sure, but it seems like it may not have worked properly in earlier releases.<sup>*</sup>

The following syntax is semantically equivalent and much more portable:

```
>file 2>&1
```

*(note the `&` in `2>&1`)*

Use it instead.

---

* According to the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), "This operator is now functional, as of Bash 4, final release."